# Drupal site front page

Tags: drupal

I've assigned a page from Pages module as home page. And now the main menu shows the menu item called 'Main' which leads to '/main' page. How can I change that to make the 'Main' menu item link to really '/' of the site ?

Updated:
Sorry if it is not clear, the 'page' i mean is really a page - ( Site building -> Pages ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the Site Information section of your admin panel, you can set a specific node to show up as the front page.  I would use the node/XX way of referencing your node, since the alias you gave the node ("main") may change.  Once you've done that, you can change your menu link to go to `<front>`, which will automatically send it to whatever node is designated as the front page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
If I mark a 'page' as to be the front page of the site, and it has a menu item, this menu item leads to something like '/main', but not the '/'. To fix it I removed any menu reference on the page properties and then in the menu editor add the required link with the path ''.
Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

On top of what everyone else has said, can I just let you know of a mistake that I made.

I had pathauto switched on, but it was set to delete old path and create a new path if the title of a page changed.

And you know what, this happened to my home page, so where the page I'd over ridden and called homepage, was now called welcometothisthatortheother (if you know what I mean).

My advise if your using pathauto is to use the nid value ( node/11 ) or make sure unlike me, that you only create new paths on page inserts rather than updates.